# Alfresco Community keeps loading

Tags: alfresco

I try to start Alfresco Community via manual start (alfresco manager tool  - Postgres and Tomcat Server), but unfortunately it keeps loading. For your better convenience, i attach you a few lines from the alfresco log file. Any idea what should i do?

> 9:29:57,101 WARN  [org.alfresco.util.RuntimeSystemPropertiesSetter]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Could not find alfresco-jmxrmi.password on
> classpath
> 19:30:02,179 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL
> 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco' with user 'alfresco'.
> 19:30:08,695 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database PostgreSQL version 9.2.4
> 19:31:11,789 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin,
> default]
> 19:31:12,070 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID:
> [sysAdmin, default] complete
> 19:31:12,273 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate):
> patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
> 19:32:35,398 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor Repository
> Template Processor for extension ftl
> 19:32:35,429 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor Repository Script
> Processor for extension js
> 19:35:09,343 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Connecting to database:
> jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco, UserName=alfresco,
> PostgreSQL Native Driver
> 19:35:09,344 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Schema managed by database dialect
> org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.
> 19:35:13,533 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Schema validation found 81 potential problems,
> results written to:
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-PostgreSQLDialect-Validation-Pre-Upgrade-alf_-3183430725471519111.txt
> 19:35:13,647 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Schema validation found 14 potential problems,
> results written to:
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-PostgreSQLDialect-Validation-Pre-Upgrade-avm_-7512141432063460367.txt
> 19:35:13,896 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Schema validation found 28 potential problems,
> results written to:
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-PostgreSQLDialect-Validation-Pre-Upgrade-jbpm_-5737410679165367310.txt
> 19:35:14,741 WARN  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Schema validation found 23 potential problems,
> results written to:
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-PostgreSQLDialect-Validation-Pre-Upgrade-act_-3173466186980288340.txt
> 19:35:15,559 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-pre-upgrade-alf_-7486225889050239999.xml.
> 19:35:15,560 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-pre-upgrade-avm_-7635637824804863260.xml.
> 19:35:15,560 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-pre-upgrade-jbpm_-5616677644800954648.xml.
> 19:35:15,561 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-pre-upgrade-act_-5265759256121984983.xml.
> 19:35:16,164 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-9187881054905799629.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-RepoTables.sql).
> 19:35:25,067 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-7048610944173087476.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-LockTables.sql).
> 19:35:25,666 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-9111962919851849560.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-ContentTables.sql).
> 19:35:27,374 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-4605317553201473968.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-PropertyValueTables.sql).
> 19:35:30,238 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-1923540951665152923.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-AuditTables.sql).
> 19:35:31,881 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-5967217534682945645.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-ActivityTables.sql).
> 19:35:33,881 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-6760638796710759808.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-UsageTables.sql).
> 19:35:34,192 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-7367942087784284032.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-SubscriptionTables.sql).
> 19:35:34,437 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-3052131204560692858.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-TenantTables.sql).
> 19:35:34,674 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-6384255534801765324.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoCreate-AvmTables.sql).
> 19:35:41,319 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-7770841650354199017.sql
> (Generated).
> 19:35:49,655 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-7062476802180431283.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoPostCreate-JBPM-Extra.sql).
> 19:35:49,685 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-2193606989039742058.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoPostCreate-JBPM-FK-indexes.sql).
> 19:35:57,881 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Executing database script
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-Update-7168291649866998015.sql
> (Copied from
> classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/AlfrescoPostCreate-JBPM-varinst-indexes.sql).
> 19:35:57,974 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Create scripts executed in 46762 ms
> 19:36:10,076 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] All executed statements:
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\AlfrescoSchema-PostgreSQLDialect-All_Statements-3634531932850451511.sql.
> 19:36:23,147 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Compared database schema with reference schema
> (all OK): class path resource
> [alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/Schema-Reference-ALF.xml]
> 19:36:25,099 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Compared database schema with reference schema
> (all OK): class path resource
> [alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/Schema-Reference-AVM.xml]
> 19:36:35,043 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Compared database schema with reference schema
> (all OK): class path resource
> [alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/Schema-Reference-JBPM.xml]
> 19:36:38,921 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Compared database schema with reference schema
> (all OK): class path resource
> [alfresco/dbscripts/create/org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect/Schema-Reference-ACT.xml]
> 19:36:58,090 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-post-upgrade-alf_-3832843618215573491.xml.
> 19:36:58,091 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-post-upgrade-avm_-132108221799615792.xml.
> 19:36:58,091 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-post-upgrade-jbpm_-3163255027450013646.xml.
> 19:36:58,092 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Normalized schema dumped to file
> F:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\Alfresco-schema-PostgreSQLDialect-post-upgrade-act_-6093218398546186087.xml.
> 19:37:00,663 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory]
> [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search,
> managed, solr]

Regards

Comment: What Alfresco version, Postgres and OS versions, how did you installed ?

Comment: I installed Alfresco Community 5a via win-installer-exe 630 MB sourceforge available (Windows 7). What should i do on this occassion regarding this problem as it is my first project? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@asimkon, please don't cross post the same issue on different forums without notice. The log you uploaded in the Alfresco Forums [Alfresco keeps loading](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/alfresco-keeps-loading/td-p/312295) tells you quite clear the issue:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

You database is not running/accessable ...

Comment: I just downloaded the win-installer-exe app 5a from https://sourceforge.net/projects/alfresco/files/ and suddenly i got the posted alfresco log file. Regards

Comment: so your issue is solved?
I suggest you do not go with the old installer. Use docker or a linux vm from well known suppliers instead. The installer just dumps the binaries on your disk and it may be hard to maintain the components like postgres, but if you read the start/stop scripts you could try to understand the required environment variables to be set for manual interaction ...

Comment: another option may be to just install postgres on your windows box and configure the jdbc connection string in alfresco-global.properties located at tomcat/shared/classes/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (windows box). That helped me a lot! Unfortunately i do not see any "installed" solr folder in Alfresco, is there any way to add and configure it manually via alfresco-global.properties and how? Regards

Comment: alfresco 5 does not have a separate solr folder. solr is deployed as a war inside tomcat/webapps/. check tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr4.xml for your path variable variables to find out which data dir is used for solr index